# Create directory denied on Samsung phone even after Storage Permissions are granted

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, file-permissions

At the launch of my app, I create a folder in storage. To achieve that I ask for permissions within `initState()`. Only when it completes should the directory check go forward.

```
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    easyDir = Directory(widget.folderPath);
    getPermissionStatus().whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {
        //never call async operations in setState, do it in a function call.
        directoryCheck();
      });
    });
  }
```

the `folderPath` is produced by the `permission_handler` package. Which for my phone is `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/easyFolder`

```
  //check if directory exists, create if not.
  Future<void> directoryCheck() async {
    // using awaits fixed my problem of setstate being called before
    // directory was created.. and calling setState at end
    exists = await easyDir.exists();
    if (!exists){
      await new Directory(widget.folderPath).create(recursive: true);
      exists = true;
    }
    setState(() {

    });

  }

Future<void> getPermissionStatus() async {
    _status = await Permission.storage.status;
    // if permission is not granted yet, request it and update _status
    if (_status != PermissionStatus.granted){
      await Permission.storage.request();
      _status = await Permission.storage.status;
    }
  }
```

This works as expected on the emulator. The app asks for permission at startup, waits for it to complete, and when allowed creates the directory.

But when installed on my Samsung phone and even a friends phone (which is Samsung) the folder cannot be created due to permission denied, even after granting permission.

This is the error I receive on my Samsung phone:

```
E/flutter (23275): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I clearly gave permission at startup of app. Whats more is when I go into the appinfo of my app it shows that `Storage` permissions are granted.

I tried installing this on Huawei and Xiaomi phones and both worked as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are the permission lines in my `AndroindManifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is the error stack if that helps:

```
E/flutter (23275): #0      _Directory.create.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:124:11)
E/flutter (23275): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (23275): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (23275): #3      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter (23275): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter (23275): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (23275): #6      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter (23275): #7      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
E/flutter (23275): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (23275): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (23275): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (23275): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (23275): #12     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (23275): #13     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (23275):
```

Comment: where exactly are you requesting permissions? what Android version are you running on your emulator and Samsung phones?

Comment: You should show us what `getPermissionStatus()` does, like @EdwynZN pointed out, without that you are unlikely to get further assistance. Also, you should avoid going ahead without knowing if you have the permission or not, because whenComplete is practically a "finally" block, meaning it will always be executed. "whenComplete method... Registers a function to be called when this future completes.  The action function is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error." [source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html)

Comment: Android 10/Q on the phones where it does not work?

Comment: I have updated my question with additional code. The Emulator is running Android version 11. While my Samsung phone is on Android version 10

Comment: @Uroš, Thanks, I put the ``whencomplete()`` in there for that purpose. What do you suggest I use in place of it?

Comment: @blackapps It does not work on the Samsung phone, which is Android 10

Comment: So now you know that it does not work anymore on Android 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find weird that the code works fine in Android 11 but not 10, because of the new scoped storage the writting permissions should fails in `Android 10 (Q)` and above

For now try this in your manifest to opt out of scoped storage in Android 10 (this will do nothing in Android 11),

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
     Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

> Caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level
> 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute
> when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be
> ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on
> those devices.

[More info about Scoped Storage here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage)

Now some questions to help you fix this problem:

> the folderPath is produced by the permission_handler

I don't recall permission_handler to return a path when asking for permissions, can you elaborate how do you get `widget.folderPath`?

> The Emulator is running Android version 11. While my Samsung phone is
> on Android version 10

How about the Huawei and Xiaomi devices, are they running Android 10 too?

What is your `compileSdkVersion`/`targetSdkVersion` in gradle or `targetSdk` in AndroidManifest?

Comment: ``android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`` fixed it. Thanks you so much, you saved me from a ton of headache :)

Comment: Beware this solution is temporary, when Android 11 gets released this won't work and you will have to do some native code because right now even path_provider is broken

Comment: Thats unfortunate.. I have no knowledge of writing native code. At this stage what can I do to avoid further headache? Or is my only option to wait for ``path_provider`` to update with a fix?

Comment: Well I am still waiting for them to fix path_provider too, for now people have been doing their own packages like android_path_provider or download_path, maybe you should check them, that's all we can do for now

Comment: Not working in android 11 man ... I'm using DIO to save image from url but not allowing me with this error (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Comment: and it won't work, you need to check a package or implement a way to use Scoped Storage to save files now